# "import: command not found" running Python script

Tags: python

I am a beginner without much knowledge of coding.
I am attempting to run the following python script... https://github.com/Sdocquir/moneyonbots/blob/master/shopify3/shopify3.py

When doing so I receive the following message

```
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 1: __author__: command not found
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 3: import: command not found
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 4: import: command not found
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 5: import: command not found
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 6: import: command not found
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 7: import: command not found
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 8: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/lxml
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium
from: can't read /var/mail/requests.adapters
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py: line 15: modes = [('Gift Card', 1), ('Credit Card', 2), ('Paypal', 3)]'
```

In the beginning of the script it says...

```
import requests
import sys, traceback
import re
import arrow
import time
import Tkinter as tk
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
```

Do I need to install other libraries to run the script?  What are the commands to install these?
I am using mac OSX.
Thank you.

ENTIRE SCRIPT: https://github.com/Sdocquir/moneyonbots

Comment: Are you sure you have python installed in your system?

Comment: @ravishankar Yes I have Python 3.5.2 installed

Answer (score 12):

This happens when your script is being run by a shell, not a Python interpreter at all.

Put a shebang on the first line of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

...or, as appropriate,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

...to specify to the operating system that it should be run with a Python interpreter.

---

You may indeed need to install some 3rd-party packages, but you'll get an error specific to the imports that fail after fixing your interpreter; at that point you can use either the same package manager you used to install Python 3 (if it was installed via MacPorts or Homebrew or similar), or use PyPi, virtualenv, or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm sorry if this is a foolish question but could you please expand on where specifically to put the line "#!/usr/bin/env python".

Comment: Needs to be the very first line of the file.

Comment: Or just run the script as `python <scriptname>`.

Comment: Ok I added the shebang and ran the script again.  I got the following error "Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/xxx/Downloads/moneyonbots-master/shopify3/shopify3.py", line 4, in <module> import requests ImportError: No module named requests"

Comment: Yep, you have to install the libraries that you currently don't have. For example you don't have **requests** and I am guessing some others too. You can google on how to install them. The easiest way is
*pip install ...*

Comment: thanks.  Also, what does this error mean? " line 167
    print "Email:           ", self.email
                            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'"

Comment: @danielBerenson, it means you're running code written for Python 2 with Python 3. The languages aren't compatible.